# Is there a word for instantiating all the things that I suppose in my argument?

Tags: epistemology, propositional-logic

Let's say I'm in the propositional logic and I say: "Socrates is a man. All men are mortal. Therefore Socrates is mortal." Sure, it is true that "Socrates is mortal" is the valid conclusion. But it is true only to us and people who know what I'm talking about. In this argument, I implicitly suppose they have some level of knowledge and also that they have the same understanding of it. For a child not knowing anything about propositional logic, the argument doesn't have to persuade them. To persuade them about validity of the argument, I would have to tell them that I implicitly supposed they know the "rules" of propositional logic. But there could be more to persuade them. How do we call this instantiation of the things that I implicitly suppose when telling something? Are there some keywords for this subject?

Comment: It is a syllogism, and a syllogism is not a propositional argument; it is predicate logic.

Comment: The [validity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic)) of an argument is a *semantical* concept: it is based on the concept of interpretation and truth. The validity of an argument can be expressed through "formalization", using place-holders (schematic variables) in order to show its generality. Thus, in the end, it requires semantical notions: truth, meaning, etc.

Comment: A concept that can be useful is that of [Logical Form](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-form/). See also: Andrea Iacona, [Logical Form : Between Logic and Natural Language (Springer, 2018)](https://books.google.it/books?id=qUJJDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: They are called presuppositions and background assumptions. And on top of them you need to presuppose background *skills*, such as being able to follow the inference rules. Carroll described what would happen when someone did not master a skill to follow *modus ponens* in a fun story [What the Tortoise Said to Achilles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_the_Tortoise_Said_to_Achilles). See also [Wittgenstein's rule-following paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wittgenstein_on_Rules_and_Private_Language#The_rule-following_paradox), which shows that "instantiating" *all* of it is hopeless.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: You may also want to look at the [frame problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_problem) concerning the representation of background assumptions when designing an AI.